# My multithreaded program is returning different values than expected

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm following an exercise from a Java book, and the exercise is a producer and consumer problem that uses the "synchronized" keyword on methods, and works with threads.

If it is okay, I will share pictures of the exercise from my book:

[image]
[image]

The outcome in the book is:

```
Put: 1
Got: 1
Put: 2
Got: 2
Put: 3
Got: 3
Put: 4
Got: 4
Put: 5
Got: 5
```

My code is the exact same as the one on the book, but the outcome varies for very large numbers such as:

```
Put: 84172
Got: 84172
Put: 84173
Got: 84173
Put: 84174
Got: 84174
Put: 84175
Got: 84175
Put: 84176
Got: 84176
```

Or:

```
Got: 116734
Put: 116735
Got: 116735
Put: 116736
Got: 116736
Put: 116737
Got: 116737
```

and so on...

If I am correct, I am aware that threads/multithreading, go hand-hand with CPU.

Q: Could my CPU be the reason for such high values? Because it is too fast?

*My CPU is: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz

Q: If the answer to the question above is negative, can you help me understand why I'm getting such high values?

Main:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Q queue = new Q();

        Producer producer = new Producer(queue);
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(queue);

        producer.thread.start();
        consumer.thread.start();
    }
}
```

Q:

```java
public class Q {
    int n;
    boolean ready = false;

    synchronized int get(){
        while (!ready){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println("Consumer thread was interrupted!");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Got: " + n);
        ready = false;
        notify();
        return n;
    }
    // ------------------------

    synchronized void put(int n){
        while (ready){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println("Consumer thread was interrupted!");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

        this.n = n;
        ready = true;
        System.out.println("Put: " +  n);
        notify();
    }
}
```

Producer:

```java
public class Producer implements Runnable{
    Q queue;
    Thread thread;

    Producer(Q queue){
        thread = new Thread(this, "Producer");
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i = 0;

        while (true){
            queue.put(i++);
        }
    }
}
```

Consumer:

```java
public class Consumer implements Runnable{
    Q queue;
    Thread thread;

    Consumer(Q queue){
        thread = new Thread(this, "Consumer");
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true){
            queue.get();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: maybe your CPU is so fast that you missed the start - the output you are showing is about 84172 cycles... the start probably was scrolled out of view (and maybe memory)

Comment: Output to a file instead or redirect the output of the execution to a file, so you will be able to see what's the actual output.

Comment: or just code the producer to stop after 10 or 100 iterations

Comment: Thank you all, you were right! I can't believe I forgot I could a add for loop for 10 cycles, and confirm for myself. My CPU is too fast, and the for loop helped. Thank you